# pikle (pkl) file for AI image generator

Tags: python, image, artificial-intelligence, pickle, generate

I'm trying to generate pictures form (StyleGAN2-ADA-PyTorch) (https://colab.research.google.com/github/dvschultz/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/blob/main/SG2_ADA_PyTorch.ipynb#scrollTo=jG7ZEc_982io).
I'm stuck to the Generate Single Images section where **I can't find the pkl file**.

I'm putting my zip file on the dataset path and on the resume_from I put '/pretrained/wikiart.pkl' which is mentioned in the train model and when I run it I'm getting an already trained result of an art painting. I'm expecting to get the results from my zipped images in the folder "datasets".